# SVN ignoring a symbolic link to a directory

Tags: svn, symlink

I have a project that contains few folders and a *symbolic link* to one of them. I want to ignore the symbolic link to avoid version control on it -which causes duplicate commits etc. How can I add this symbolic link to ignore list without affecting the original directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [delete](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/svn-book.html#svn-ch-9-sect-1.2-re-delete) that link from SVN and make SVN [ignore](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/svn-book.html#svn-ch-7-sect-2.3.3) it. Restore the link manually then.

Haven't tried it myself though.